# Mail won't connect to Exchange account

Tags: mail.app, catalina, exchange

Mail won't connect to my school Exchange account. It was working perfectly fine yesterday, but today it's asking for a password. When I put in the correct password, it says it's wrong and won't connect. I know that the password is correct because the web version of Outlook works fine with that password.

I've not changed anything since it was last working. I'd just locked the computer, and when I came back today it wasn't working.

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with Mail 13.4.

EDIT: It's not just in Mail that it isn't working. When I check the account in System Preferences and other connected apps(Notes, etc) it also asks for the password and doesn't accept it.

Comment: You might need to get the school to sort this out. I have similar issues with a business account. If it ever asks for the password [on the Mac or iPhone], ignore it & eventually it goes away. As soon as you try to put a password in, then you're stuck, because it will never accept it. The web access still works fine whilst this error is happening.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would removing and re-adding the account work, or should I just leave it alone?

Comment: I'd ask whoever administrates the account, rather than keep trying & risking messing it up further. [My own business structure has a 'supervisor' account that needs to be used to reset it if I mess mine up]